# Generate ERD/DDL/C# classes from Class diagram Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, ddl, class-diagram, enterprise-architect, erd

I have a class diagram created by Enterprise Architect (.eap project file). 
Is there a way that I can generate the ERD(entity relationship diagram),C# classes or the DDL(SQL Data definition) query from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can generate C# classes and DDL from your model.

See the section [Generate Code](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/software_engineering/generatesourcecode.html) in the help file to know more about code generation.

The section [Generate DDL](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/database_engineering/ddl_generation.html) explains how to do DDL generation.

Going from a class model to a database model (ERD) is a bit more complicated. In order to do so you'll need an MDA transformation. Read more about it in the section [Model Transformation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/model_transformation/mdastyletransforms.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find a way to do this with fillowing .eap file here [UBL2.1Structural](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/49065/UBL2.1Structural.EAP.zip)

Comment: Thanks Geert. I'll follow your Guidelines. I'm a rookie to enterprise architect.